# Checking if char out of not fully filled array is empty

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic, delete-operator

As you may know, if you want to delete any type of dynamically allocated array (that you used the operator `new[]`on), you should use `delete[]` to get rid of it.

Now, I would like to know if there was any way I'd be able to delete a single object of a dynamically allocated array.

```
char* someNewArray = new char[someInt];

//Add values to the array

delete &someNewArray[2] //or maybe delete[] instead of just delete
```

Comment: What your meaning of "empty" ? How you want user to enter "empty" chars in `usr_answer` in between elements ?

Comment: An uninitialized array could contain anything.  If you want it to have some value you can check then set each element to that value.  You'd be better off using `std::string`.

Comment: @P0W Basically my plan for this is to get his answer, get the amount of chars in that given answer (that don't point to nothing) and then create a new resized char array. He doesn't have to enter empty elements. Simply enter a char collection with less chars than the array is able to hold.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Doesn't it automatically "contain" values as soon as I call cin? Aren't there just elements that are NULL? I'd like to know a way how to check if these are NULL.

Comment: It contains what was typed, up to the first whitespace character, a NULL, then whatever else happened to be in the uninitialized array.  The problem in the code you have shown is you're performing the comparison incorrectly.  `if(c == 0)` would work, but I wouldn't say it is the right thing to do.  What happens if 1001 characters are input?  Using `std::string` avoids all of these issues as it will resize to fit the content and you can easily determine that size.  If you must use a raw character array then use `strlen` to find the length of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot.

Operator `new` in its array form allocates *one single memory element* able to contain the number of elements you asked. You can the only deallocate the whole block with `delete[]`.

If you want to deallocate blocks one by one, you will have to allocate them with same granularity, that is one by one.

EDIT :

It would have little sense for object of size 1 because the overload of allocating a block will be large facing `sizeof(char)`. In that case it is more efficient to allocate a new block of size `someInt -1`, use `memcpy` and then free initial block with `delete[]`

```
char * tmp = new char[someInt -1];
memcpy(tmp, someNewArray, 2);
memcpy(tmp+2, someNewArray + 3, someInt - 3);
delete[] someNewArray;
someNewArray = tmp;
```

But it you add an array of larger objects say `LObj`, instead of

```
LObj * newArray = new LObj[someInt];
```

you could use :

```
LObj ** newArray = new (LObj *)[someInt];
for (i=0; i<someInt; i++) {
    newArray[i] = new LObj;
}
```

Then is makes sense to use :

```
delete newArray[2];
newArray[2] = NULL;
```

Comment: It'd be really nice of you if you could provide an example.